# Cannot find name 'const'

Tags: angular, typescript, constants

I'm developing an Angular app and am trying to use the Typescript 3.4 feature "const assertion" like this:

```
const counterSettingsDefaults = { setTo: 10, tickSpeed: 200, increment: 1 } as const;
```

But I get the compile error:

> "Cannot find name 'const'.ts(2304)",

Which indicates to me that this functionality is not available.

Typing `ng --version` in powershell gives me the following versions of Angular and Typescript:

```
 Angular: 9.0.0-rc.7 
 typescript: 3.6.4
```

**What could be wrong, where can I investigate this further?**

Comment: Maybe your Angular app uses an older version of TypeScript. Therefore check your package.json and the dependency `typescript`.

Comment: I thought so too but I guess that's where the ng --version: typescript: 3.6.4 comes from? In package.json it's: "typescript": "~3.6.4"

Comment: Your syntax is correct and the Typescript version you are using supports this feature. so the problem must be someplace outside of this one line. try creating a new project with just typescript to rule out some possibilities.

Comment: do you get this error inside your IDE? Or from the compilation of the angular app? If it's the first, then perhaps your IDE is using an old typescript version

Comment: Works fine for me. This feature has been in TypeScript since 3.4.

Comment: everything seems to be OK, here is a detail description: https://mariusschulz.com/blog/const-assertions-in-literal-expressions-in-typescript

Comment: Thanks for the answers, the VS code Typescript version is shown in the bottom right corner and is at 3.6.3 so that can't be the problem either.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this problem here. Hurray!

"Open a TypeScript file.

Click the TypeScript version to the bottom right in the Status Bar.

Choose Use Workspace Version from the message box."

- https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/project-by-ts-global-variable/6582/7

Comment: I'm glad that works for you but it still doesn't work for me.